# jQuery change ID of all DIVs with ID < than $(this).attr("id");

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an sortable grid of elements, that updates its value to DB after user moves the element. The problem is, I don't know how to update the id of all previous elements to a new one without reloading the page.

In PHP, I would do something like this (code from FAQ of one of my older pages), but I can't use PHP (it has to happen without any page reloading, right after user places element he moved):

```
if ($old_order > $order){
    $result = dbquery("UPDATE faq SET orders=orders+1 WHERE orders>='$order' AND orders<='$old_order'");
}else{
    $result = dbquery("UPDATE faq SET orders=orders-1 WHERE orders>='$old_order' AND orders<='$order'");
}
```

I would like to do that with jQuery, basically I have 7 elements with id from 0 to 6 and every time user changes the position, I serialize it and send it with ajax to an php code that saves it.

**What it does now:**

1. Move elemtent 1 to position 4.
2. Saves and works.
3. Move element 3 to position 2
4. Moves element 1 from position 4 back to his old one, as the ID of it
   is still 1 and not 4.

**What I want to do:**

1. Move element 1 to position 4
2. Change ID of element 1 from 1 to 4
3. Change ID of element 2, 3 and 4 by -1 to id 1, 2 and 3

I hope somebody understands me and can help me.

jQuery code I actauly use:

```
$(".content-page").sortable({
    start: function(e,ui){
        ui.placeholder.height($(".sorted-icons").outerHeight(true));
        ui.placeholder.width($(".sorted-icons").outerWidth(true));
    },
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    items: '.sorted-icons:not(.new_icon)',
    update: function(e,ui) {
        var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&order=icons' + '&content_id=' + $(this).attr("data-shortcut-id");
        console.log(order);
        $.post("page_ajax.php", order).done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }).fail(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

Html code basically looks like this with content inside of that div thats irelevant:

```
echo "<div class='sorted-icons' id='icon_$id'>";
```

If you have any questions, just comment and Ill try to answer them and update the queston.

**Fixed jQuery:**

```
var i = 0;
$(this).children('.sorted-icons').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('id', 'icon_' + i);
    i++;
});
```

Still have problem with PHP part tho. Its saving them in weird orders.

Comment: I don't understand - are you able to USE php here?

Comment: No, I have to use jQuery, as I cant reload the page every time user moves some element.

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this please

Comment: I can't as you can see them rearanged normally, but when you refresh the page and it loads the data from DB, its ordered wrong. What I can do, is maybe make an fiddle that shows you the ID and the ID it should have as alert.

Comment: the html would be enough, together with your javascript/jquery

Comment: Its really hard for me to explain it. http://jsfiddle.net/xabxt3re/16/ - Every time you move the element, it would call and ajax that saves its position according to its ID and its position in serialize. What happens tho is, that if you move it once from 1 to 4, it gets saved in DB as number 4. If you move another one tho, the code sees that Eh, element with ID 1 is in position 4, so i should move it back. So what I need is, to change element 1 ID to ID 4 and ID of elements 2, 3 and 4 to ID 1, 2 and 3. If you understand me. Another thing is, elemens are in DB saved in array.

Comment: Well, ok, I fixed that, but it looks like I have some problem with my PHP code :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I had one little bug in my PHP code, but I managed to fix the jQuery with really simple pice of code:

```
$(".content-page").sortable({
    start: function(e,ui){
        ui.placeholder.height($(".sorted-icons").outerHeight(true));
        ui.placeholder.width($(".sorted-icons").outerWidth(true));
    },
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    items: '.sorted-icons:not(.new_icon)',
    update: function(e,ui) {
        var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&order=icons' + '&content_id=' + $(this).attr("data-shortcut-id");
        console.log(order);
        $.post("page_ajax.php", order);
        // THIS PART //
        var i = 0;
        $(this).children('.sorted-icons').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('id', 'icon_' + i);
            i++;
        });
        // THIS PART //
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

Hopefully might help somebody else.